# Haskell Tree foldt on Tree with variable members

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

I'm trying to create a custom data type Tree. The definition is below:

> A tree can be defined as either a leaf (identified by the keyword "Leaf") containing a single piece of information (i.e. it is a node with no child), or a node (identified by the keyword "Node") with a single piece of the information, plus a list of trees – each element in the list represent a subtree rooted at the corresponding child. Note that under this definition, a tree can never be empty.
>   That means a tree can either be:
>
> - Leaf data; or
> - Node data [data, data, …] -- there can be zero or more tree inside the list

This is my code:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a [ Tree a ] deriving (Show)

foldt :: (a -> a -> a) -> Tree a -> a
foldt f (Leaf a)     = a
foldt f (Node a [])  = a
foldt f (Node a [b]) = f a (foldt f b)
```

It compiles, but when I try to run:

```
let myTree = Node 'A' [Node 'B' [Leaf 'E', Node 'F' [Leaf 'I', Leaf 'J', Leaf 'K']], Node 'C' [Leaf 'G', Leaf 'H'], Leaf 'D']
foldt min myTree
```

Instead of the expected output `'A'`, I get the below error:

```
CSC207a4.hs:(6,1)-(8,38): Non-exhaustive patterns in function foldt
```

What part of my function is non-exhaustive, or have I defined the data type incorrectly?

**Update:**

I may have solved the non-exhaustive pattern, I now have this, but it claims Tree is not defined:

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a [ Tree a ] deriving (Show)

```
foldt :: (a -> a -> a) -> Tree a -> a
foldt f (Leaf a)     = a
foldt f (Node a [])  = a
foldt f (Node a [(Tree x)])  = f a (foldt f x)
foldt f (Node a [(Tree x):xs]) = f a (foldt f (f x (foldt f xs)))
```

Comment: You've only accounted for when the `[Tree a]` is 0 elements or 1 element.  What if I had `Node 1 [Leaf 2, Leaf 3]`?

Comment: I think I found a fix for that, but now it claims that Tree does not exist when I try to use it.

Comment: `Leaf` and `Node` are not actually keywords—they're data constructors.

Comment: so what does that mean?

Comment: A keyword is something like `let`, `if`, `then`, etc., that is built into the language syntax. Data constructors are how you build up values in Haskell out of smaller pieces. Pattern matching on data constructors is then how you take the smaller pieces out of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. After staying up all I night I had a flash of inspiration. Here it is:

```
module CSC207a4 where

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a [ Tree a ] deriving (Show)

foldt :: (a -> a -> a) -> Tree a -> a
foldt _ (Leaf a)    = a
foldt _ (Node a []) = a
foldt f (Node a b)  = f (foldt f x) (foldt f (Node a xs))
    where
        x:xs = b
```

This passes all of the test cases, and answers my question.

Comment: I knew you could get it. You should, however, replace the `b` with `x:xs` directly. This whole exercise is a bit peculiar. The more usual fold for this (very peculiar) tree type looks like this: `foldTree :: (a -> b) -> (a -> [a] -> b) -> Tree a -> b`. Can you write that one?

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, :) I don't really have time to delve into that, but it's good to know I solved one of the more difficult of the bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can get some help from GHC by turning on warnings. The "big hammer" is `-Wall`:

```
-- At the very top of the file
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
```

A less noisy approach will work too:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fwarn-incomplete-patterns #-}
```

Either of these will give you an explicit list of the patterns you failed to match, at compile time.

The reason putting `Tree` in your pattern won't work is that `Tree` is a *type* constructor (the sort you make by putting them on the *left hand* sides of `data` or `newtype` declarations). Only *data* constructors (the sort you make by putting them on the *right hand* sides of `data` or `newtype` declarations) can be matched in patterns.

Comment: so, what is a possible solution to my problem? I'm having a very hard time understanding it.

Comment: @Himself12794, yes there is a solution to your problem! You will understand it soon. See [learnhaskell](https://github.com/bitemyapp/learnhaskell) for some good resources.

Comment: @Himself12794, just to simplify things a drop, I suggest you start by writing a version to fold lists first, then binary trees, then trees defined by `data Tree = Node a [Tree a]` (called rose trees), and then finally the weird ones you're actually dealing with.

Comment: I guess that will have to do for now. I'm just not getting good examples of anything in the class I am currently in.

Comment: I don't really have the time needed to learn from another source, and I'm not getting anything useful from my course, which is requiring me to solve this.

Comment: @Himself12794, I'm sorry you're in such a bind. You may want to try the #haskell channel on FreeNode; it's more conducive to one-on-one interactive help than SO.